# How to make if some condition, checkbox to be checked

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, checkbox, checked

I have to show students  with checkboxes and if definite teacher teaches these students, they must be ckeched. If these students are not his students, it has not to be checked. I have two queries to copmare 2 values, but in my case when they are equal, students aren't checked in the ckechboxes, but it is written: `checked="checked" > >`. And How to close my checkbox, it is shown `> > >` before names of the students.

My view is:

```html
<?php
foreach($select_students as $student) 
{
 
?>
  
    <tr><td class='col-md-2'>

    <input type="checkbox" name="student[]"  value="<?php echo $student->user_id; ?>"  
    <?php  foreach($select_teachers_students as $select) {
      echo $student->user_id == $select->student_id ?  'checked="checked"' : ''
      ; ?> >
    

  <?php } 

    echo $student->username; ?>
  
    </td><td>
```

My model is:

```html
public function select_students() {
  
        $this->db->select('users.user_id, users.username, users.school_id, users.class, users.division, users.role_id, schools.school_name, schools.region,class_divisions.division');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('class_divisions','class_divisions.id=users.division','left');
        $this->db->join('schools','schools.school_id=users.school_id','left');
        $this->db->where('(users.deactivated_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR users.deactivated_at IS NULL) AND users.role_id = 1 ');
        $this->db->where('users.school_id',$this->uri->segment(4) );
        $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->result();
 }


public function edit_students() {
     
        $submit=$this->input->post('change');
        $date = new DateTime("now"); 
        if(isset($submit)&&($submit=='Промени ученици')) {
          if($this->input->post('student')) {
          foreach($this->input->post('student') AS $student) {
          $data = array(         
            'student_id' => $student,
            // 'teacher_id' => $this->uri->segment(3),
             'created_at' => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')         
          );
          $this->db->where('teacher_id',$this->uri->segment(3));
          $this->db->update('teacher_student_conn', $data);    
      
            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
            {   
                return true;
            } 

              return false;
            }
          }
      }

    }
```

My controller is:

```html
  public function edit_students()
    {
        if($this->admin_model->edit_students()) {
            echo "Tou changed teacher successfully!";
            $teacher_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $school_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
            header('Refresh: 2; url=/survey/index.php/admin/edit_students/'.$teacher_id .'/' .$school_id);
        }
        else
        { 
           
            $data['dynamic_view'] = 'edit_students'; 
            $data['select_students']=$this->admin_model->select_students();
            $data['select_teachers_students']=$this->admin_model->select_teachers_students();
            $data['teacher_name']=$this->admin_model->teacher_name();
            $data['menu']=$this->menu_model->get_menu();
            $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);
        }
    }
```

Now I edited my model and it is:

```html
public function select_teachers_students() {
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('teacher_student_conn');
      $this->db->where('teacher_student_conn.teacher_id',$this->uri->segment(3) );
      $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->result();
 }
public function edit_students() {
     
        $submit=$this->input->post('change');
        $date = new DateTime("now"); 
        if(isset($submit)&&($submit=='Промени ученици')) {
          if($this->input->post('student')) {
           foreach($this->input->post('student') AS $student) {
            if($this->input->post('student')==$this->select_teachers_students()) {
             
          $data = array(         
            'student_id' => $student,
            
             'created_at' => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')         
          );
          $this->db->where('teacher_id',$this->uri->segment(3));
          $this->db->update('teacher_student_conn', $data);    
      
    }
      else if($this->input->post('student')!=$this->select_teachers_students()) {
        
         $data = array(         
            'student_id' => $student,
             'teacher_id' => $this->uri->segment(3),
             'created_at' => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')         
          );
         $this->db->insert('teacher_student_conn', $data);   
      }
      }
            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
            {   
                return true;
            } 

              return false;
            }
          }
      

    }
```

But inserts rows that I have already. I tried to make a check with function select_teachers_students() and if they are there, I don't want to insert again - I want to update them. And how to Set value for the checkboxes when it is checked, to insert `value="<?php echo $student->user_id; ?>"` But when, checkbox is not checked and I push submit button, to insert `Value='0'`. If they aren't there, I want to insert.

Comment: I changed the way I'll show it. It's more complex in that way. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one `checked="checked"` is required for each `input` element. Then, first calculate if student is checked, and later (when is build the output) use that.

```
<?php
foreach ( $select_students as $student ) {
    $checked = false;
    foreach ( $select_teachers_students as $select ) {
        if ( $student->user_id == $select->student_id ) {
            $checked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf( '<tr><td class="col-md-2">'
            . '<input type="checkbox" name="student[]" value="%s" %s />'
            . '</td><td>%s</td></tr>',
            $student->user_id,
            $checked ? 'checked="checked"' : '',
            $student->username );
}
?>
```

Comment: My problem is that when you open this page, it will be checked that students which you teach. How to update or insert in database this query? If I add some more students and I use "insert" in my query in model, I'll insert again that students, that are already inserted. If I use update, I'll change student for that teacher, but I won't add new students to that teacher.

Comment: No one query that meets both at the same time. First, identify those that already exist. Second aggregates that do not exist. Finally removes leftover.

a) `$oldIds = ` _some query that select ids_

b) `$newIds = ` _the request of the html form_

1) `foreach ( $oldIds as $id ) { if isset( $newIds[$id] ) unset( $newIds[$id] ); unset( $oldIds[$id] ); }`

2) `foreach ( $newIds as $id ) { ` _query to insert_ ` }`

3) `foreach ( $oldIds as $id ) { ` _query to delete_ ` }`

Comment: I edited my question. If you have enough time to see it. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an extra > between your

```
?> >      

  <?php
```

tags. Since this is inside a foreach loop, it will get executed multiple times.

On a more serious note, your view logic needs a facelift. Use a template engine like Smarty.

Answer (score 1):

The code used to output the checkboxes don't seem to be correct. Try the following:

```
<td class='col-md-2'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="student[]"  value="<?php echo $student->user_id; ?>"
    <?php foreach($select_teachers_students as $select) { ?>
          <?php echo $student->user_id == $select->student_id ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>            
    <?php } ?>  
    />
    <?php echo $student->username; ?>
</td>
```

This should work. In your case, the loop was not setup properly...

Comment: Thanks, it works now! :) I don't know what to use - update or insert in my query. There are students that are checked if this teacher teaches them amd not if he doesn't teach them. I want to change students - if you check other checkboxes with students, to be insert in table `teacher_student_conn` for that teacher. But if they are checked and they are already inserted and I don't want to insert again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
<?php  foreach($select_teachers_students as $select) {
      echo $student->user_id == $select->student_id ?  'checked="checked"' : ''
      ; ?> >
```

You should use in_array function to check teacher teaches any student or not.
Example:

```
select_teachers_students=array(12, 34, 25);// Student ids array 
if(in_array($student,select_teachers_students){
     echo "checked='checked'";
}
```

because of mistake its adding one  > at end.